# How to sort two columns at once in datatables

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have a table like below , I want to sort column A ascending and column B descending.

`A    B    C
1    4    string1 
2    11   string2 
1    13   string3
2    43   string4`

And, I want to sort by both A (ascending) and B (descending) at once, to get this:

`A    B    C
1    13   string3
1    4    string1 
2    43   string4
2    11   string2`

Right now I can able to sort one column with following code

`oTable.api().columns( ['.acol'] ).order("asc").draw();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://datatables.net/reference/api/order()):

You can specify multiple columns in order command. In your case:

```
oTable.api().columns( ['.acol', '.bcol'] )
            .order([ [ '.acol', 'asc' ], [ '.bcol', 'desc' ] ])
            .draw();
```

Comment: Hi , i tried this , its sorting both columns in descending... strange..

Comment: Hi.. I just edited my answer (with a slight change - now I use a big array of arrays). Can you test it now please?